# cannot see how to mock or write unit tests without marking too many methods virtual

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

We are starting to add unit testing to our solution and I am writing unit tests using Moq.

I wrote my first 10 tests without mocking and was fine, but now that I have reached tests that require mocking, every method I try to test seems to require partial mocking (well; the method I am testing needs to have actual implementation and every other inner method it calls need to be faked).

Problem is to write my tests I have to make too many changes to the original code to make it testable. Adding interfaces to every class is one thing, and removing dependencies from method and having them as parameters might be acceptable, too (though I guess is going to happen way too often), but it seems aslo that I need to mark every dependency method I need to fake as virtual. This is way too much changes to the original code just to make it testable.

So; my question is, is this how I am supposed to do this, or is there a way of writing unit tests without this many changes, and virtualizing the methods also?

Here is example of 1 unit test I am writing:

```
public class ContrastControlViewModel : ViewModelBase, IContrastControlViewModel
{
    public void UpdateCompositePropertyValues(String propertyName)
    {
        if (SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream != null)
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "ContrastCurve":
                    if (_enableContrastControlUpdate)
                    {
                        UpdateContrastCurve();  // Only updates the local line graph display of the contrast controls
                        _enableContrastControlUpdate = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public IVideoProcessingSubstreamViewModel SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream
    {
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ContrastControlViewModelTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateCompositePropertyValues()
    {
        //scenarios:                8 tests, could be separated
        foreach (String input_propertyName in new string[]{"ContrastCurve", "other"})
            foreach (var input_SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream in new IVideoProcessingSubstreamViewModel[] { null, (IVideoProcessingSubstreamViewModel)(new Mock<IVideoProcessingSubstreamViewModel>()).Object})
                foreach (bool input_enableContrastControlUpdate in new bool[]{ true, false})
                {
                    //Arrange:
                    bool UpdateContrastCurve_called = false;
                    var vm = new Mock<ContrastControlViewModel>(10, 10, 200, 200, 240, 240) { CallBase = true };
                    vm.SetupProperty(m => m.SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream);          //throws NotSupportedException
                    vm.SetupProperty(m => m._enableContrastControlUpdate);
                    vm.Setup(m => m.UpdateContrastCurve()).Callback(() => UpdateContrastCurve_called = true);

                    //Act:
                    vm.Object._enableContrastControlUpdate = input_enableContrastControlUpdate;
                    vm.Object.SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream = input_SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream;
                    vm.Object.UpdateCompositePropertyValues(input_propertyName);

                    //Assert:
                    Assert.IsTrue(UpdateContrastCurve_called == (input_propertyName == "ContrastCurve" 
                        && input_SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream != null && input_enableContrastControlUpdate == true));
                }         
    }
}
```

So; right now I get a NotSupportedException because "SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream" has to be virtual to be faked. If I start doing that everything ends up getting marked virtual. Later, I end up even marking methods of other classes virtual.

Comment: There´s no simple way to make legacy-code testable. It assumes much refactoring. So you should refactor until your code it *is* testable. Thus your question is way too broad and unspecific.

Comment: I would highly recommend _Working Effectively with Legacy Code_ by Michael Feathers. It contains good strategies for starting to make legacy code easier to test and refactor.

Comment: When testing legacy code, I would suggest focusing on more integration tests. Refactoring legacy code is risky without a proper test-suite. If you need unit tests you can use a commercial product like [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com/) that is not limited to interfaces/virtual methods.

Comment: Different mocking framework vendors use different technologies behind. What you observed is the limitation of moq, but other frameworks like Typemock Isolator does not have such a limitation, https://www.typemock.com/isolator Thus, it is a broad question that no good answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you won't need to mock the class under test.

Mocking `ContrastControlViewModel` so you can see if `UpdateContrastCurve` was called is a smell that they are separate concerns and should not be in the same class.

I would refactor this so:

- There is a constructor with an interface passed in that is the interface for a new class/service that contains the `UpdateContrastCurve` method.
- Change your test to mock this new class/service when your instance under test of `ContrastControlViewModel` is created.
- Assert that the mock method `UpdateContrastCurve` was or wasn't called given the parameters to the `UpdateCompositePropertyValues` method.

The classes would be changed to look like this:

```
public class ContrastControlViewModel : ViewModelBase, IContrastControlViewModel
{
    private IUpdateContrastCurveService _updateContrastCurveService;

    public ContrastControlViewModel(IUpdateContrastCurveService updateContrastCurveService)
    {
        _updateContrastCurveService = updateContrastCurveService;
    }

    public void UpdateCompositePropertyValues(String propertyName)
    {
        if (SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream != null)
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "ContrastCurve":
                    if (_enableContrastControlUpdate)
                    {
                        _updateContrastCurveService.UpdateContrastCurve();  // Only updates the local line graph display of the contrast controls
                        _enableContrastControlUpdate = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public IVideoProcessingSubstreamViewModel SelectedVideoProcessingSubstream {get;set;}
}
```

And the test would look like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class ContrastControlViewModelTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateCompositePropertyValues_Should_update_contrast_curve_when_ContrastCurve_and_enabled()
    {
        //Arrange:
        IUpdateContrastCurveService updateContrastCurveService = new Mock<IUpdateContrastCurveService>();
        var vm = new ContrastControlViewModel(updateContrastCurveService.Object);
        var propertyName = "ContrastCurve";

        //Act:
        vm.UpdateCompositePropertyValues(propertyName);

        //Assert:
        Assert.IsTrue(updateContrastCurveService.Verify(x=>x.UpdateContrastCurve()));       
    }
}
```